# Почему компилятор требует точки с запятыми, когда она имеются?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <ctime> 
using namespace std; 



int main() 
{ 
srand(time(0)); 
int n, m, i, j, a, b, max=0; 
cout « "Enter n" « endl; 
cin » n; 
cout « "Enter m" « endl; 
cin » m; 
int **Y = new int*[n]; 
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{ 
Y[i] = new int[m]; 
} 
cout « endl; 
cout « "Enter a: " « "\n"; 
cin » a; 
cout « "Enter b: " « "\n"; 
cin » b; 
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{ 
for (j = 0; j < m; j++) 
{ 
Y[i][j] = a + rand() % (b-a+1); 
cout « Y[i][j] « " "; 
} 
cout « endl; 
} 
int ii, ij; 
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{ 
for (j = 0; j < m; j++) 
{ 
if (Y[i][j] > max) 
{ 
max = Y[i][j]; 
ii = i; 
ij = j; 
} 
} 
} 
cout « "Max value: " « max « " in [" « ii+1 « "][" « ij+1 « "]" « endl; 
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{ 
delete Y[i]; 
} 
delete Y; 

system("pause"); 
return 0; 

}
```

Comment: Может быть <<, а не «?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может, у вас и в самом деле не `<<` и `>>` использованы, а эти невнятные `«` и `»`?

Исправьте их на правильные операторы С++, и все скомпилируется.

Правда, с предупреждениями о потенциально неиспользуемых переменных, но это уже другой вопрос...